# problematic read commited behavior - what should i expect?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, jta, transaction-isolation, postgresql-15

small simplified question regarding isolation levels using wildfly, hibernate jpa, jta with isolation level READ_COMMITED. assuming the following scenario:

1. Thread 1, on table SomeTable, using JPA with a new transaction, update a specific entity property (a single row in the DB)
2. Thread 2, on table SomeTable, using JPA with a a different transaction, before transaction #1 is commited, executes a findAll (select *).

my question is: from a transaction Isolation perspective (READ_COMMITED). what is expected:

a) Thread 2 blocks on the read operation until thread 1 commits

b) thread 2 is able to read without blocking and, of course, get all data excluding what Thread 1 did not commit yet

I would think option b is the correct one as this is what isolation means in my mind.
however, I have encountered 2 database/driver implementations, the first implementing what I described in option a and the second implemented option b.
so I am a little confused, not sure if there is a mandatory behavior here and one db simply has a bug.
your comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As defined by the JDBC-4.3 spec ([JSR-221](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html)), item 10.2 (and I'm pretty sure it goes way back), the proper behavior when you define the transaction isolation to TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED "*means that any changes made inside a transaction are not visible outside the transaction until the transaction is commited*", what would "*prevent dirty reads, but nonrepeatable reads and phantom reads are still possible*".

A dirty read occurs when a uncommitted change is read outside a transaction. A nonrepeatable read occurs when two subsequent reads of a same row are different because between them a commit occurred. A phantom read occurs when different rows may be returned by different reads.

Going back to your description, when using `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED` as transaction isolation level should lead to the "b" scenario: thread 2 should be able to read data existent before thread 1 commits, and if it tries again, should read the new data (probably a phantom read), all without blocking.

The block behavior described in "a" scenario should occur only when isolation is set to `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` (partially, only for the same row) or to `TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE`.

Per spec, if a JDBC driver do **not** support a lighter transaction isolation, it should adopt a higher (more restrictive) level and, if it can't, throw a `SQLException. Probably this is the case with your first JDBC driver, that used a` REPEATABLE_READ`or`SERIALIZABLE`level when you set it to`READ_COMMITED`. The spec does not mandates that the JDBC driver implementation reports this "upgrade" of level. You may test the supported isolation level using` supportsTransactionIsolationLevel` method.